# hg push abort: http authorization required. i am pushing to my local bitbucket repository

Tags: mercurial, authorization, bitbucket, required

i am trying to push my changes to my local remote repository in bitbucket. i have access to this repository. but when i do this, it is showing like this. it should show prompt for password but it is not showing.

```
$ hg push
pushing to https://sat801@bitbucket.org/sat801/i4330-notification-sm
abort: http authorization required
```

and in my .hg folder, this is my hgrc file

```
[ui]
username = sat801 <*******@example.com>
editor = nano

[paths]
default = https://sat801@bitbucket.org/sat801/i4330-notification-sm
```

i can neither push anything in my local repo nor pull anything from it. it is showing the same error

```
abort: http authorization required
```

please let me know how to solve this problem

Comment: I suggest you start with contacting bitbucket support: https://bitbucket.org/support and looking at the documentation to verify your setup. Did it work before?

Answer (score 8):

I think you either have to use `sat801:mypassword@bitbucket.org` (i.e. include your password) or forego putting your username in.

Comment: This worked for the main repo, but fails for the subrepo

Comment: TortoiseHG recommends against this, since it can get embedded into the hgrc that goes out to the whole team.

Answer (score 8):

I had to do this:

### ~/.hgrc

```
[auth]
bb.prefix = bitbucket.org
bb.username = johndoe
bb.password = *********
bb.schemes = http https
```

Where "bb" can be anything, and prefix corresponds to the http server domain

Comment: So much mucking around with mercurial_keyring and this is all I had to do? Ha so good.